# Unable to debug in xcode 8.2.1 using swift 2.3

Tags: ios, xcode8.2

My project is in swift 2.3. currently using xcode 8.2.1 . while debugging (using po command)  getting below error.

**Swift expressions require OS X 10.10 / iOS 8 SDKs or later  in Xcode 8.2.1.**

Comment: check your simulator's iOS version, and your mac's oS X version.

Comment: One more thing as we using Xcode latest versions the swift 3.0 will be more use rather than 2.3, And you have to update your system with latest versions.

Comment: currently using Mac os version is 10.12.2.

Comment: simulator ios version 10.2

Comment: @Rakesh. Does Xcode 8.2.1 supports swift 2.3??

Comment: @GouravJoshi.. If i want to use swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.2.1 means does my code works?

Comment: offcourse it works.

Comment: @Rakesh. Apple had given info that swift 2.3 will be depreciated in future release of Xcode .(by the time Xcode 8.2 release).my doubt is can i update my Xcode to 8.2.1 ?Does my code work which is in swift 2.3

Comment: you are right . Currently using swift 2.3 in xcode 8.2.1 and got problem like Swift error in module testDebug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger. and failed to get module 'test' from AST context. I dont know why is happing. But your code works.

Comment: Thank u.. I will update my project

Comment: @UmaMadhavi are you using xcode 8.2.1?

Comment: No,currently i didn't update yet ? Is there any issue .